# Flex charts: How to remove shadow with CSS?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

How do I remove my columns' shadow with CSS?

I know I could do this:

```
<mx:seriesFilters>
  <mx:Array />
</mx:seriesFilters>
```

But I'd really like my CSS to control all the visuals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is exposed as a style by default.  However, you can add whatever CSS style you want, like this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinstyle_3.html